# My HeadPhones ARCTIS NOVA 1 Audio Work But not the Mic

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, microphone, openstack

OS: Kubuntu 23.04 x86_64
Kernel: 6.2.0-26-generic

I have wired ARCTIS NOVA 1 headset , the audio works quite well. I have tried almost all profiles but unable to get the mic working.

Any help would really be appreciated.

[Sound Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0U7rB.png)

[Profiles Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6k3J6.png)